# CSS to adjust an image in certain size div automatically

Tags: html, css

I have a div on which I defined following CSS rules

```
<style>
    .image-preview {
        height: 600px;
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .image {
        width: auto;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<div class="image-preview">
    <img src="abc.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

Suppose if `width:50%` is `300px` and **abc.jpg** is of `500px` it comes out of the div. I want to keep the image in the `div` as center aligned and with maintaining the aspect ration of it.

I have given the `width:auto` but this is not working. I have not much experience with CSS so please ignore if this is too basic to ask.

Thanks!!

Comment: `.image{width: 100%;}` width: 100% is the base of responsive. If you want to maintain the aspect ratio you must don't set the height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use display flex to center your image with this you make sure that the images always maintains its aspect ratio...

```css
.image-preview {
        height: 600px;
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
    }

    .image {
       max-width:100%;
       max-height:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-preview">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150" class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: I am fixing the height of div container. Is there any way to set height dynamically based on its parent div's height?

Comment: Yes it is just use height with percentages...in the image, careful if you use this you might need to remove the max-height property so it doesn't lose its aspect ratio..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use flexbox, which is probably the best tool to align items in divs. You can find out more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp.

```css
    .image-preview {
        height: 600px;
        width: 600px; /*whatever you want*/
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .image {
        height: 400px; /*Any value would still keep it vertically centered thanks to the align-items property*/
        width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-preview">
    <img src="https://www.ancestry.com/wiki/images/archive/a/a9/20100708215937%21Example.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

The `justify-content` property handles the horizontal alignment, and the `align-items` property handles the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

So, image is a inline element:

```
img {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto; //this is center your image
   height: auto; // this will make it ration
   max-width: 1200px; //or whatever is the size of your image
}
```

This will make your image full responsive, centered and ration.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .image-preview {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}

    .image {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        max-width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-preview">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/600/any" class="image">
</div>
```

You can do it by setting height 100%; width:auto to image.